# Tektro HD-M275 rear brake making grinding noises while braking

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-pads, rotor

I got Tektro HD-M275 hydraulic disc brakes with 180mm rotors, front brake is working perfectly with no issues. Under light braking rear brake works normally without any noises or vibrations, but as soon as I start to apply little more pressuer on the lever rear brake start to make grinding noises. The noise that it's making is not the same as the rotor rubbing against the pads, it's very strange. It sounds like metal rubbing against each other and during heavy braking I can feel like small vibrations through the seat. I've tried to align the brake but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

The one thing that bothers me are the brake pads, to be more specific the left brake pad. It's placed directly in line with the brake caliper itself, so maybe when I brake the right pad presses onto the rotor and pushes it to rub againts the caliper?

Comment: Please take out pads and check there's some friction material left

Comment: The bike is about a month old, so I don't think the pad material should be a problem

Comment: But you still have to check or the bike would be perfect! When so new, the shop you bought it from is supposed to look after you and fix it

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your brake is not properly aligned to your rotor. I would try to align it properly so the brake does not touch the rotor if it's not pressed.
I do it by loosening the two bolts on the caliper, pushing the brake and the tighten the bolts again.

If this doesn't fix your problem i found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ukbike/comments/10edn1h/brake_juddering_turkey_gobble_noise/) on Reddit.

This was his solution:

> Yeah, I replaced with Shimano pads and Shimano rotors. Much better now. Fairly certain the Tektro rotor design was the main cause so probably didn't need new pads too, but for the sake of a few quid I didn't wanna risk ruining new rotors if the old pads were contaminated.